# Have I got a mystery croissant lurking in my Lego collection?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I've loved every minute of a massive LEGO sort-out recently, but a mystery imposter lurked in there.

My kids swear blind that we've had these two types of croissant for over seven years, but I don't think it can be so. Surely LEGO never made two types that were so close in appearance? And the imposter brick doesn't say "Lego" anywhere on it.

On the left we have an authentic LEGO piece (of which we own four or five), and on the right, the possible imposter (we only have one, which is telling). I thought it could be Playmobil or Sylvanian Families, or something like that.

[image]

[image]

My kids swear blind that the one on the right came from a Belville set, but a web search suggests not. They also insist it doesn't belong with any of their other toys, but I'd rather trust an internet stranger than my own kids ;)

**So my question is - is the piece on the right definitely LEGO or not?** And massive kudos if you can spot what it really is.

Comment: That does not look like a croissant to me...

Comment: _Surely_ the one on the left is a pig in a blanket. It _could_ be a croissant, I suppose, but that looks awfully like a hot dog wrapped in something. The one on the right does look like a croissant.

Comment: @user91988 It looks like that so that the minifigures can hold it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The right piece is not Lego.

1. It cannot be connected to any other piece. No stud, anti stud or shaft that fit a Minifig hand, like the 1 at the left has.
2. Searching both [bricklink.com](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=33125&name=Croissant&category=%5BFood%20&%20Drink%5D#T=C) and [brickset.com](https://brickset.com/parts?query=croissant) only 1 croissant mold is found

Also Lego pieces of this size will contains the Lego name and copyright.

Comment: We have one Belville set at home (7586 - Sunshine Home) and I can confirm that it includes the mold linked in this answer (left one in pictures).

Comment: It looks like the other answer about Barbie is correct, but it's worth pointing out than in the Lego Friends sets there are loads of different "accessory" pieces which don't have holes and can't fit into another piece:  hairdryers, hairbrushes,etc.  The croissant could easily be something from one of those sets.

Comment: @MaxWilliams LEGO Friends accessories have at least one option to connect with other elements. Items you've mentioned have so-called  "3.18mm" or "bar" connection option. Actually, left croissant has two of these on each end, unlike the right one.

Answer (score 34):

It looks like a possible match for these doll accessories.

["This listing is for a Barbie coffee shop or bakery accessories. Included are hot chocolate mugs, a coffee to go mug, croissants, muffins, donuts, a to go box, and a bakery display plate."](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/barbie-bakery-cafe-coffee-shop-diorma-1852840046)

[image: Croissants, muffins, donut and coffee shop doll accessories]